# Python Pandas: Convert complete Row to single Column

Tags: arrays, matrix, row

look at the image below and help me to solve the issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbul9.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print(df['Placeholder'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use DataFrame.transpose

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html